# Regular Expressions in PHP: Matching to the UTS18 standard

Tags: php, regex, unicode

The Unicode Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR) has a wealth of information regarding the relationship between languages and characters. For example, you can determine which characters are utilized in a particular language by looking at the [misc.exemplarCharacters](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/by_type/misc.exemplarCharacters.html) chart. The raw data for these charts are stored as XML files and the exemplar characters are stored as regular expressions according to the Unicode Regular Expressions standard [UTS18](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/).

Here's a few examples of what UTS18 regex expressions look like:

```
1. [a à b c ç d e é è f g h i í ï j k l ŀ m n o ó ò p q r s t u ú ü v w x y z]
2. [অ আ ই ঈ উ ঊ ঋ এ ঐ ও ঔ ং \u0981 ঃ ক খ গ ঘ ঙ চ ছ জ ঝ ঞ ট ঠ ড {ড\u09BC}ড় ঢ {ঢ\u09BC}ঢ় ণ ত থ দ ধ ন প ফ ব ভ ম য {য\u09BC} ৰ ল ৱ শ ষ স হ া ি ী \u09C1 \u09C2 \u09C3 ে ৈ ো ৌ \u09CD]
3. [a á b ɓ c d ɗ e é ɛ {ɛ\u0301} f g i í j k l m n {ny} ŋ o ó ɔ {ɔ\u0301} p r s t u ú ū w y]
```

I'm using PHP and SimpleXML to parse the XML data and isolate these regex strings. Now, I would like to match individual multi-byte characters to these regular expressions. I'm currently using the [mb_ereg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-match.php) function, which yields one or more of the following warnings (depending on the regex):

```
mbregex compile err: premature end of char-class in ...
mbregex compile err: empty range in char class in ...
mbregex compile err: empty char-class in ...
```

Any ideas as to why this isn't working?

Comment: Do U set mb_internal_encoding and mb_regex_encoding? Pls show Ur code where U use mb_ereg_match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Sergey, I added the following lines before calling the mb_ereg_match() function:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
```

This addition eliminated two of the warnings listed above. I was only left with the following warning:

```
mbregex compile err: empty char-class in ...
```

After some additional debugging, I discovered that a handful of the CLDR XML files do in fact contain empty regular expression strings. For example, in `kn.xml` we have the following line:

```
<exemplarCharacters type="auxiliary">[]</exemplarCharacters>
```

I believe these lines are erroneous, as the expected behavior would be to simply leave the line out altogether (which is mostly the case throughout the CLDR).

Thus, I was able to eliminate this last error by simply throwing out empty regex strings.

Hope this helps someone else!